# I can't get the input text in the input tag?

Tags: html, dom

This is very strange to me:

```
document.getElementById('orderNumber')
```

> returns `<button class="popup" id="orderNumber">order Number</button>`

```
document.getElementById('orderNumber').value
```

> returns ''

all the operation is after dom fully loaded and after I input the type,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `value` of the element, that element has to *have* a `value` attribute set:

```
<button class="popup" id="orderNumber" value="this is the value">order Number</button>
```

The value being retrieved by:

```
var value = document.getElementById('orderNumber').value;
```

or if you want the text of the element, try retrieving the `textContent` (or `innerText`):

```
var ordernumberEl = documet.getElementById('orderNumber'),
    text = orderNumberEl.textContent || orderNumberEl.innerText;
```

A general [JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Dja63/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('orderNumber').innerHTML
```